# How to get props passed down to child component with React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using React w/ Redux I know what I want, but I'm not sure how to get there.

I have a reusable 'ImageCarousel' component that I want to pass props down to. The component needs to receive 'id', 'img', and 'title' props. The 'id', 'img', and 'title' comes from an API. The response will return an array with 20 images.

Is there a way to get the props without adding them to Redux-Store? Maybe something like this?

```
class Parent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     <<Fetch from an API, API return an array of 20 items >>
  }

  render(){
      return <ImageCarousel id={GetThisDynamically.id} img={GetThisDynamically.url} />
  }
}
```

My solution will spit out 20 ImageCarousels.

```
this.props.movies.map(movie => {
   return <ImageCarousel id={movie.id} img={movie.url} title={movie.title} />
})
```

How do I get 1 Carousel with 20 images with the ability to pass props down dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what "pass props down dynamically" means. Props are always dynamic, that's the point of them. What's the issue with the code in your question? Seems basically like the way to do it.

Comment: I guess what i'm trying to say is...Is there a way to pass props to the component without having to put an 'id' 'img' 'title' props inside of Redux-Store? If you look at my solution it renders 20 carousels. Maybe a helper function to extract the properties?

Comment: As the another responder mentioned we would need a bit more info in order to help. But generally, how this should work is that on `componentDidMount` you would call a Redux action dispatcher, that would call the API for you, that API response will be processed and sorted in Redux state, which will then prompt your component to update with this state as props, when you pass those to your 'ImageCarousel'.

Comment: @j_nguyen Yes you can do that by calling your API directly in your did mount and passing that information to your 'ImageCarousel' but at the expense of diverging from your app's uni-directional flow.

One other way would could do so without hurting the uni-directional flow too much is my keeping the params needed for the API call (if they differ) into Redux, then use it to mount your component, make the API call in the didMount and pass the data to your 'ImageCarousel'